# Is it possible to generate correct OpenAPI yaml file for Spring Rest Controller in case response as ResponseBodyEmitter instead of ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, streaming, openapi

I can easily generate OpenAPI yaml file for RestController methods that return ResponseEntity such as

```
public ResponseEntity<SomeResponseDto> getSomething() {
   ...
   return responseEntity.ok(dto);
}
```

Is it a way to generate correct OpenAPI yaml file for RestController that use the ResponseBodyEmitter return value such as

```
@GetMapping(path = "/streaming")
public ResponseBodyEmitter getSomeStream() {
   ResponseBodyEmitter emitter = new ResponseBodyEmitter(streamTimeout);
   ...
   //------------------------
   // In another thread
   emitter.send("Some text");
   emitter.complete();
   //------------------------
   ...
   return emitter;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done because of the following open-api limitation - [Support for Streams in Responses #1576](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1576)